# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called while reading from a json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read 'f1.txt' into a DataFrame so I executed this code  :

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('f1.txt') as f:
    txt=f.read()
with open('try.json','w') as j :
    json.dump(txt,j)

df=pd.read_json('try.json')
```

but I got this error : ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

And these are 2 line example from 'f1.txt' file

{"timestamp":"2020-02-26T16:45:30.120251+0100","flow_id":448074922775995,"in_iface":"wlp2s0","event_type":"dns","src_ip":"192.168.43.141","src_port":35194,"dest_ip":"192.168.43.1","dest_port":53,"proto":"UDP","dns":{"type":"query","id":54362,"rrname":"push.services.mozilla.com","rrtype":"A","tx_id":0}}
{"timestamp":"2020-02-26T16:45:30.120729+0100","flow_id":2229545752778649,"in_iface":"wlp2s0","event_type":"dns","src_ip":"192.168.43.141","src_port":54757,"dest_ip":"192.168.43.1","dest_port":53,"proto":"UDP","dns":{"type":"query","id":8245,"rrname":"push.services.mozilla.com","rrtype":"AAAA","tx_id":0}}
{"timestamp":"2020-02-26T16:45:30.122342+0100","flow_id":448074922775995,"in_iface":"wlp2s0","event_type":"dns","src_ip":"192.168.43.141","src_port":35194,"dest_ip":"192.168.43.1","dest_port":53,"proto":"UDP","dns":{"version":2,"type":"answer","id":54362,"flags":"8185","qr":true,"rd":true,"ra":true,"rrname":"push.services.mozilla.com","rrtype":"A","rcode":"REFUSED"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-02-26T16:45:30.122504+0100","flow_id":2229545752778649,"in_iface":"wlp2s0","event_type":"dns","src_ip":"192.168.43.141","src_port":54757,"dest_ip":"192.168.43.1","dest_port":53,"proto":"UDP","dns":{"version":2,"type":"answer","id":8245,"flags":"8185","qr":true,"rd":true,"ra":true,"rrname":"push.services.mozilla.com","rrtype":"AAAA","rcode":"REFUSED"}}

Comment: The `f1.txt` contains an invalid JSON format. Are you sure this is what you want to read?

Comment: Also, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html, your data needs to be in the format specified in that link

Comment: @Akshay i fact that file is generated from Suricata ( the original name file is eve.json ) so i don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: It's not a valid JSON data. Use https://jsonlint.com/ to test it